# Segmentation Fault, can't figure out why

Tags: c, arrays, random, segmentation-fault

```
#include <time.h>

int perm_table[255];
float rand_vectors[255][3];

initialize_random_numbers()
{
    int i;
    float tmp[3], length;
    for (i=0; i<255; i++)
    {
        perm_table[i] = rand() % 255;

        tmp[0] = (float)(rand() % 1000);
        tmp[1] = (float)(rand() % 1000);
        tmp[2] = (float)(rand() % 1000);

        printf("\n%i", i);

        memcpy(rand_vectors[i], tmp, sizeof(float)*3);
    }
}
```

Running this prints every number from 0 to **253** (on 255), before giving a Segmentation Fault.

Commenting out this line

```
perm_table[i] = rand() % 255;
```

removes the error.

I am completely beaten by this. Any help?

Comment: Do not put tags in question headlines, please.

Comment: works for me on [ideone](http://ideone.com/FQxzR). Are you sure this is the code you are invoking? If `perm_table` is of size 254 - it fits the error. Or could it be somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Did you try compiling and running this code alone? It should work fine! The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: The code looks OK; my bet is that you didn't post the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: This code looks correct, and indeed compiles and runs to completion here. I note that i<255 is the terminating condition so the last number printed will be 254; and this will not have a newline, which may cause it to not have been flushed to TTY on your system before the segfault. Are you absolutely sure your segfault does not actually occur later, after this code returns? Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: gdb will always tell you where the segmentation fault is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in this code for me.

The segfault probably occurs **after** the function returns and not because of this function.

The fact that the last number printed is `253` is because the stream is not flushed after 
`printf("\n%i", i);` and as the segfault occurs after the function, the stream never got flushed.

By default, when connected to a terminal, `stdout` is line-buffered. To flush `stdout` either call `fflush(stdout)` or print a `'\n'` character.

Comment: Uhh...yes. Which is why "memcpy(rand_vectors[i], tmp, sizeof(float)*3);
" uses float*3.   I'm not sure what you mean with this.

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be on the printf statement.

Just try modifying it to:

```
printf("%d\n"); // basically having the \n in the end.
```

sometimes you can't see the output on the screen because it's still in printf's buffer. `\n` makes sure the buffer is cleared.